# PhotoSwipe: Responsive Images Example

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

Using the JS from this CodePen http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/ZYbPJM I want to add responsive images as functionality.

Can I simply replace:

```
        // create slide object
        item = {
            src: linkEl.getAttribute('href'),
            w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
            h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
        };
```

with

```
var items = [

    // Slide 1
    {
        mediumImage: {
            src: 'path/to/medium-image-1.jpg',
            w:800,
            h:600
        },
        originalImage: {
            src: 'path/to/large-image-1.jpg',
            w: 1400,
            h: 1050
        }
    },

    // Slide 2
    // {
    //     mediumImage: {
    //         src: 'path/to/medium-image-2.jpg',
    //         ...
    //     
    // ...

];
```

and then add

```
// create variable that will store real size of viewport
var realViewportWidth,
    useLargeImages = false,
    firstResize = true,
    imageSrcWillChange;

// beforeResize event fires each time size of gallery viewport updates
gallery.listen('beforeResize', function() {
    // gallery.viewportSize.x - width of PhotoSwipe viewport
    // gallery.viewportSize.y - height of PhotoSwipe viewport
    // window.devicePixelRatio - ratio between physical pixels and device independent pixels (Number)
    //                          1 (regular display), 2 (@2x, retina) ...


    // calculate real pixels when size changes
    realViewportWidth = gallery.viewportSize.x * window.devicePixelRatio;

    // Code below is needed if you want image to switch dynamically on window.resize

    // Find out if current images need to be changed
    if(useLargeImages && realViewportWidth < 1000) {
        useLargeImages = false;
        imageSrcWillChange = true;
    } else if(!useLargeImages && realViewportWidth >= 1000) {
        useLargeImages = true;
        imageSrcWillChange = true;
    }

    // Invalidate items only when source is changed and when it's not the first update
    if(imageSrcWillChange && !firstResize) {
        // invalidateCurrItems sets a flag on slides that are in DOM,
        // which will force update of content (image) on window.resize.
        gallery.invalidateCurrItems();
    }

    if(firstResize) {
        firstResize = false;
    }

    imageSrcWillChange = false;

});


// gettingData event fires each time PhotoSwipe retrieves image source & size
gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {

    // Set image source & size based on real viewport width
    if( useLargeImages ) {
        item.src = item.originalImage.src;
        item.w = item.originalImage.w;
        item.h = item.originalImage.h;
    } else {
        item.src = item.mediumImage.src;
        item.w = item.mediumImage.w;
        item.h = item.mediumImage.h;
    }

    // It doesn't really matter what will you do here, 
    // as long as item.src, item.w and item.h have valid values.
    // 
    // Just avoid http requests in this listener, as it fires quite often

});


// Note that init() method is called after gettingData event is bound
gallery.init();
```

in between

```
        // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
        gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);

        // insert responsive image code here 
        gallery.init();
```

?

`item` and `items` are two different objects so I am not sure where to put what.

Looking at the index.html from the website folder of the PhotoSwipe repo there is responsive image code in the JS section of that file however that does not work, PhotoSwipe is not initialized, so the default example from the repo does not work (or needs extra code to get working/initialised?)

Is there a working example for responsive images with PhotoSwipe somewhere?